# How are USB-HID devices handled that have no outgoing endpoints?

Tags: java, android, usb-hid

I've been working on a USB-HID Java for Android plugin that needs to communicate with a number of devices, and I've been mostly successful using the bulkTransfer() method.

Right up until I encountered a hardware device that didn't have any outgoing endpoints. This specific one had 2 interfaces and 1 endpoint on each one.  Both were incoming, so it was not possible to send commands to it using bulkTransfer().

My questions:

1) Is it possible send the same commands to the device using the controlTransfer() method instead?

2) Can I use the same byte array I was passing in to bulkTransfer()?

3) If both of the above are true, what does the value and index parameters do on the controlTransfer():

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#controlTransfer(int,%2520int,%2520int,%2520int,%2520byte%5B%5D,%2520int,%2520int)

I looked at:
[how is different between controlTransfer and bulkTransfer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42668273/how-is-different-between-controltransfer-and-bulktransfer)

But it didn't really answer my main question.

Comment: What are you trying to send TO an HID? Seems weird.

Comment: Commands to operate a blood glucose monitoring device to download various kind of data.

Comment: Interesting... Definitely makes sense that it'd have a bulk out pipe in that case. I'd probably make it a CDC/virtual com port though based off this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/reading-data-from-a-glucose-meter

Looks like some meter makers have a software integration guide. You might be able to figure out what the magic request ID's are to make it work for this vendor.

Comment: ...and by that, you might be able to call them up and ask them if they don't have an open guide.

Comment: I'm guessing that the request index and value is 0, as the NodeJS Module who's interface I'm doesn't support these kind of parameters, or at least it doesn't seem to be using them in the code that I'm porting from (which is Tidepool btw.)  But now I have enough information to get unstuck, so thanks.

Comment: Worst case scenario, if you can get it working on your computer, you can use wireshark and sniff the USB transactions. That should tell you everything.

Answer (score 1):

First as a note, HID's tend to use interrupt IN rather than bulk transfers. This is NOT the same thing as the control pipe or a bulk pipe. When you move a mouse or a keyboard (typically) it'll will send an interrupt message to your computer so the OS doesn't have to constantly poll the control pipe for reports. In android, this is done with `queue`/`requestWait`.

I've personally never seen an HID with a bulk pipe.

All devices have endpoint 0 which is a bidirectional control pipe. If you control the device's firmware, you could send custom commands on the control pipe. So in theory, you could do that and use the same byte array. But you need to know what your device is expecting in terms of request id, index and value. Index would likely be 0 (interface descriptor; `UsbInterface.getId`). Value also depends on what your device is expecting (try 0).

For reference, here's the [HID spec.](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hid1_11.pdf)